# How to convert milliseconds to date in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I store date from Calendar.getTimeInMilliseconds() in SQLite DB.
I need to mark first rows by every month in SELECT statement, so I need convert time in milliseconds into any date format using SQLite function only. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Do you mean a date as seen in UTC, or the date as seen in a particular time zone?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

One of [SQLite's supported date/time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) is Unix timestamps, i.e., seconds since 1970.
To convert milliseconds to that, just divide by 1000.

Then use some [date/time function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get the year and the month:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', MillisField / 1000, 'unixepoch') FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Please see the below answer by @bsvtag. That one includes `'localtime'`

Comment: @Mikitz06 These milliseconds timestamps are defined as being in UTC. Whether the result needs to be UTC or in some local time zone depends on the application.

Comment: you are the maannn!!

Answer (score 29):

Datetime expects epochtime, which is in number of seconds while you are passing in milliseconds. Convert to seconds & apply.

```
SELECT datetime(1346142933585/1000, 'unixepoch');
```

Can verify this from this fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d41d8/223

Comment: This query helped me a lot. Now I am able to get last 15 second records by comparing the date in table with last 15 seconds like this
```select distinct abc, time_in_millis as createdDate from your_table where datetime(time_in_millis/1000, 'unixepoch') >= time('now', 'localtime', '-15 seconds') order by time_in_millis desc;```

Answer (score 22):

Do you need to avoid milliseconds to date conversion or function to convert milliseconds to date?
Since sqlite date functions work with seconds, then you can try to

- convert milliseconds in your query, like this
  `select date(milliscolumn/1000,'unixepoch','localtime') from table1`
- convert millis to seconds before saving it to db, and then use date function in sql query

Comment: This should be the correct answer, because without the localtime parameter, the time is not correct (GMT is being taken care of).

Answer (score 0):

> select date(milliscolumn/1000,'unixepoch','localtime') from table1

this is better for localtime other than GTC.

But depend on [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) I used '%F-%T' as formatter, why result is null?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).