# How change my date format in Custom Adapter?

Tags: android, date, listview, android-adapter, date-format

I think the problem is in my custom Adapter when I setText datePage

I have this format  lWed Jun 15 14:38:00 CEST 2016

I want 15/06/2016

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Page> {

    Context context;
    int ressource;
    TextView tvTitreList;
    TextView tvDateList;
    TextView tvTagList;
    Page page ;
public MyAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList <Page> data ) {
        super(context, 0, data);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_perso, parent, false);
        }
        tvTitreList = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitre);
        tvDateList = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvTagList  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag);
```

This part of my class MyAdapter

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        tvTitreList.setText(getItem(position).titrePage);
        tvDateList.setText(getItem(position).datePage.toString()); // <==dateFormat? How I put in ?
        tvTagList.setText(getItem(position).texteTag);
```

Comment: Use a `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Okey @cricket_007 but where and how ?

Comment: Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or [DateUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html).

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19217898/2308683

Comment: Alternatively, just do the string conversion in SQLite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977230/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-in-sqlite

Comment: Apply the Date format to `getItem(position).datePage`... The Date object that you want to format

Comment: maybe it's stupid question but i don't know how apply date format in my datePage...

Answer (score 1):

Format the date using SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(datePage);
```

Comment: thanks but I can't put String formattedDate in my constructor Page,  
because there is String title Date datePage and texteTAg

 listPageTagArray.add(new Page(idPage,titrePage,datePage,tagPage));